# How to concatenate arrays in Snowflake with distinct values?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a MERGE scenario with an `ARRAY_AGG()` function in the main script. Once I have a match I'd like to combine the arrays from the source and target table but don't want to add existing values. I've looked at using `ARRAY_CAT()` but it doesn't return the expected output

This is the query:

```
SELECT
  ARRAY_CAT(ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('VALUE 1', 'VALUE 2'), ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('VALUE 1', 'VALUE 3')) arr_col
```

But this returns:

| ARR_COL |
| --- |
| [ "VALUE 1", "VALUE 2", "VALUE 1", "VALUE 3" ] |

And what I need is :

| ARR_COL |
| --- |
| [ "VALUE 1", "VALUE 2", "VALUE 3" ] |

Is there an easy way to achieve this except converting to string, removing the dups with regex then splitting to array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ARRAY_DISTINCT` after `ARRAY_CAT` inline:

```
SELECT
  ARRAY_DISTINCT(ARRAY_CAT(ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('VALUE 1', 'VALUE 2'), ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('VALUE 1', 'VALUE 3'))) as arr_col
```

returns `["VALUE 1", "VALUE 2", "VALUE 3"]`

Comment: ah so they added `ARRAY_DISTINCT` finally :) . Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 2):

I've created an UDF in the end that allows me to do this as a scalar function

```sql
// Distinct Concatenate
create or replace function array_dcat(array1 variant, array2 variant)
    returns variant
    language javascript
    comment = 'Returns a distinct concatenation of two arrays'
as
$$
     return Array.from(new Set([...ARRAY1,...ARRAY2]));
$$
;
```

I used if as follows

```sql
SELECT
  ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('VALUE 1', 'VALUE 2') arr1,
  ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('VALUE 1', 'VALUE 3') arr2,
  ARRAY_CAT(arr1, arr2) sn_array_cat,
  ARRAY_DCAT(arr1, arr2) udf_array_dcat;
```

And returns

| ARR1 | ARR2 | SN_ARRAY_CAT | UDF_ARRAY_CAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [ "VALUE 1", "VALUE 2" ] | [ "VALUE 1", "VALUE 3" ] | [ "VALUE 1", "VALUE 2", "VALUE 1", "VALUE 3" ] | [ "VALUE 1", "VALUE 2", "VALUE 3" ] |

Answer (score 1):

Using `FLATTEN` and `ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT F."VALUE") AS ARR_COL
FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(
     ARRAY_CAT(ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('VALUE 1', 'VALUE 2'), 
               ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('VALUE 1', 'VALUE 3'))
    )) f
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified it a bit so that the results were sorted as well:

```
 const myArr = Array.from(new Set([...ARRAY1,...ARRAY2]));
 myArr.sort()
 return myArr
```

Comment: The question is related to SQL. Your answer takes action on JavaScript side. Not directly related to the question.